# How do I make a Lunar Calendar for a planet with three moons and two suns on either side?

Tags: moons, astronomy, day-night

The planet is about three to five times the size of Earth and it shares a solar system with 13 other planets and they have an ∞ shaped orbit around two suns on opposite sides of the solar system. The three moons of the planet are differently sized and the biggest is the farthest while the smallest is the closest. The planet takes about 247 Earth days to go around each Sun so in total it takes 493 Earth days for it to complete a full orbit. Each moon moves at different paces as well, the smallest rotates around the planet at twice the speed that our moon takes to rotate around Earth, the middle sized moon is about the same speed as our moon, and the biggest is three times slower than our moon. There is an event that happens only every ten years on that planet where all three moons align with each other and are visible together for eleven nights.

(Ps: Yes it is the same as my first question but I've done a bit of rewriting of the lore so the planet's gravity doesn't crush everything into paste. And I've only put in the necessary info this time, hope it helps.)

Comment: How humans choose to subdivide time and whether it's associated with any natural phenomena is entirely arbitrary. We have a requirement that questions on this site are specific enough to not have many valid answers. In short we're here to help you solve specific worldbuilding problem, not build your world for you.

Comment: @sphennings All I was asking was help with making a calendar, I never asked you to make it. That was all I was asking for. I was not expecting anyone to do it for me. In my bio it is literally stated that I am still in school so how the hell would I know how to make a calendar?

Comment: The stack exchange model takes a bit of getting used to. Not every question about worldbuilding can be asked on this site. Taking the [tour] or visiting the [help] can give you more information. As for why your question was closed, a calendar is just a system for organizing days. Any system of organizing days, that has some relation to the moon could be considered a lunar calendar. Any process that results in any such system is a valid way to make a calendar. This results in a question that is far too broad for this site. You can always [edit] your question to ask something more specific.

Comment: When a closed question is edited, it is automatically added to a review queue, and if the issues have been addressed it will be reopened. Instead of asking how to build a calendar, try creating a calendar yourself. When you encounter a specific issue, ask us for help resolving that in particular. Remember that as a worldbuilder you get to decide how things work in your world, and you are the final authority on whether something works or not. Let your creativity run wild. We'll happily help you solve any specific problems you have.

Comment: Lunisolar calendars in the real world function essentially like this: The moon takes 354 days to go around the earth 12 times and the earth takes 365 days to go around the sun once.  This leaves a gap of 11 days, so every 2.5 years or so you need to add a month to make them match.  People cared because they wanted their calendars, based on the moon, to match their planting seasons, dependent on the sun.  Your world is going to work the same way.  Which celestial movements will matter for a calendar depend on which ones matter for the practical things calendars are used for.

Comment: The standard calendar might not even follow every moon.  We have used the moon historically to set month lengths because it's a consistent thing that we can follow to do so.  If we had two or more moons, we might just follow the one whose orbital period matched up the best with the sun and ignore the others.  If we had a weird orbit, how we matched the lunar orbits to the solar orbit would depend on how that weird orbit impacted when it gets hot and cold, when it rains, etc.  It's possible that one moon that lines up particularly well with the sun is used for the main calendar, while a

Comment: different calendar uses a different moon or all the moons and is used for ritual purposes only.  In this case, the calendar doesn't need to match up with the solar calendar.  An example of a calendar like this is the Islamic Lunar Calendar, which doesn't add months to line up with the solar year, which is why Ramadan is always at a different time.  This is fine for this calendar because it isn't used for planting, but solely for religious purposes.  If you want a ritual calendar that agrees with your harvest season though, you need some kind of lunisolar calendar.  Multiple calendars for

Comment: different purposes are common.  The greeks, for example, used a lunisolar calendar for ritual planning and a calendar that had nothing to do with the movement of celestial bodies, divided up into 10 arbitrary months, for state planning.  A particular set of natural conditions don't inherently lead to particular calendar systems.  Calendar systems are created to solve timekeeping problems.  What calendars you need depend on your local timekeeping problems, hence why we can have both the Mayan and Gregorian calendars on earth, despite both cultures sharing a common sun and moon.